# Scroll doesn't work properly when list View adapter was set dynamically

Tags: android, listview, scroll

My Activity contain one Custom ListView which is implemented by Array Adapter. Single row contains one TextView which store time: 
Format is:  **HH:MM mins**.
This textView updates at **every one minute**.

**Problem is**: When there are more items in List View and during updation at every one minute scroll in List View doesn't work smoothly like in normal.
**So how can I make scroll smoothly during time updation in TextView.**

For Update at Every one minute I used BroadCast receiver :

```
 //use action time tick for getting update every minute
     IntentFilter mTime = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
```

This is object of BroadcastReceiver

```
  private BroadcastReceiver mtimeInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            setQueueAdapters();
        }
    };
```

Code of setQueueAdapter()

```
 private void setQueueAdapters() {
         arrayOfUsers_waiting = db.getQueuedList();
         waiting_adapter = new WaitingUsersAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers_waiting, this); // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        lvWaiting.setAdapter(waiting_adapter);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you update your list? Please show your code.

Comment: Just try reducing the numbers of items in your list. If you recycle the list item then your time may not be updated or work as you expected.

Comment: I just added three TextView and one checkbox.

Comment: You have to notify your adapter in the receiver, not always to recreate it

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will check.